# $PATH variable is behaving oddly

Tags: macos, bash, path

When I `echo $PATH` on the command line, I get:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:
```

...except it repeats all that for way longer [hundreds of times].  I did some research on where `$PATH` gets set, and I checked `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `/etc/profile`, and `/etc/paths` [I'm on Mac OS X 10.10.1], and nothing looks like it could be putting this in the `$PATH`.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

It pretty much has to be something in one of those files (or ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc). If you don't see anything in any of those files, I'd try renaming them to something inactive, opening a new Terminal window, and seeing if the PATH is long; if not, add them back one by one and see when the problem appears. Then at least you'll know which one to concentrate on.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute these suspected startup files with `-xv` switches, to see what's going on behind the screens.

Comment: Good idea. I'd set the PATH back to something sane first (e.g. `PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin`), so it'll be more obvious when it gets blown up.